# Why can't I type in terminal after hitting binding.pry or byebug when running rails test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pry

When running the test suite for my Rails application, whenever I hit a `binding.pry` or `byebug`, my terminal gets corrupted-- what gets echoed to the terminal isn't what I'm typing and the only way to get things back to normal is to interrupt the process and run `reset`

Any ideas what the issue could be? I'm not sure where to start.

Here's my Gemfile:

```html
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

gem 'rails',      '6.0.2.1'
gem 'puma',       '3.12.2'
gem 'sass-rails', '5.1.0'
gem 'webpacker',  '4.0.7'
gem 'turbolinks', '5.2.0'
gem 'jbuilder',   '2.9.1'
gem 'bootsnap',   '1.4.5', require: false
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.4.1'
gem 'pry'
gem 'pry-rails'
gem 'bcrypt',     '3.1.13'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.4.1'
  gem 'byebug',  '11.0.1', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console',           '4.0.1'
  gem 'listen',                '3.1.5'
  gem 'spring',                '2.1.0'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '2.0.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara',                 '3.28.0'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver',       '3.142.4'
  gem 'webdrivers',               '4.1.2'
  gem 'rails-controller-testing', '1.0.4'
  gem 'minitest',                 '5.11.3'
  gem 'minitest-reporters',       '1.3.8'
  gem 'guard',                    '2.15.0'
  gem 'guard-minitest',           '2.4.6'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '1.1.4'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

# source 'https://rubygems.org'
# git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

# ruby '2.7.1'

# # Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
# gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.3', '>= 6.0.3.2'
# # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
# gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.4'
# # Use Puma as the app server
# gem 'puma', '~> 4.1'
# # Use SCSS for stylesheets
# gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
# # Transpile app-like JavaScript. Read more: https://github.com/rails/webpacker
# gem 'webpacker', '~> 4.0'
# # Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
# gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# # Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
# gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
# # Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# # gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# # Use Active Model has_secure_password
# # gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# # Use Active Storage variant
# # gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

# # Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
# gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.2', require: false

# group :development, :test do
#   # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
#   gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
# end

# group :development do
#   # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
#   gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
#   gem 'listen', '~> 3.2'
#   # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
#   gem 'spring'
#   gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
# end

# group :test do
#   # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
#   gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
#   gem 'selenium-webdriver'
#   # Easy installation and use of web drivers to run system tests with browsers
#   gem 'webdrivers'
# end

# # Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
# gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. In particular, I notice that if I use byebug in a controller action, and the response times out then I can't type in the terminal. Currently, I'm upgrading to Rails 6.1 (from 6.0) and using byebug in any model/controller doesn't allow me to type.

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing a very similar problem; my terminal output is inconsistent, repeated, and I can't type when I hit a breakpoint.

#### TLDR: Rails 6 added ([by default](https://rubyinrails.com/2019/03/27/rails-6-parallel-tests/)) parallelized tests. These seem to trigger byebug breakpoints simultaneously in different worker processes. To fix, disable parallel tests.

This seems to be a [known issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/37207).
To fix, I simply commented out the indicated line in `test_helper.rb` that enables running tests in parallel:

```rb
# test/test_helper.rb
class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # ...
  # comment out this line: 
  # parallelize(workers: :number_of_processors)

  # ...
end
```

##### Notes

- I noticed that the issue was connected to parallel testing since when the breakpoint triggered I saw my breakpoint and the surrounding code repeated 4 times (with the prompt `(byebug)` repeated three times, too:
  [image]
- This didn't start until I updated to Rails 6.1. I wasn't having this issue with Rails 6.0 for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue using pry on github.com/rails/rails which does not have a `test/test_helper.rb` as referenced in [Matt's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1038034/matt) response.

The issue was resolved by:

- Run tests in serial by setting `PARALLEL_WORKERS=1`. [Example](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/contributing_to_ruby_on_rails.html#running-tests-in-serial)
- Run a single test with `-n test_long_test_name`. [Example](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/contributing_to_ruby_on_rails.html#running-a-single-test)